# unsure why ng-click isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hey there I'm new to js Angular and can't figure out what I've done wrong, how do I put an object method inside the ng-click function:

```
  <div class="container" ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="exercise-icon col-xs-2"> 
        <img ng-src="{{ exercise.icon }}">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="exercise-name"> {{ exercise.name }} </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 counters">
        <span class="decrease">-</span><span class="count"> {{ exercise.count }}  </span>
             <span class="increase" ng-click="{{exercise.increase($index)}}">+</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is the controller script:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.exercises = [
    {
      icon: 'img/pushup.jpg',
      name: 'Pushups',
      count: 20
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/squat.jpg',
      name: 'Squats',
      count: 15
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/pullup.jpg',
      name: 'Pullups',
      count: 10
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/row.jpg',
      name: 'Rows',
      count: 10
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/lunge.jpg',
      name: 'Lunges',
      count: 10
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/stepup.jpg',
      name: 'Step Ups',
      count: 10
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/situp.jpg',
      name: 'Sit Ups',
      count: 15
    }
  ];

  $scope.increase = function($index) {
    $index.count++;
  };

}]);
```

The exercise icon, name and count are all showing however the click function is not working for some reason, is the syntax correct for inserting a object method into a ng-click? I couldn't find any applicable answers online. 
  The functionality I would expect is count to increase everytime + is pressed.

Comment: why using `exercise.increase($index)`? you can call `increase($index)`

Comment: <span class="increase" ng-click="exercises.count =exercises.count+1 ">+</span>

Comment: I don't want the function inside the html Ved

Comment: any particular reason for this. With my way , yo can achieve your result without any function.

Comment: True but I was taught to try and keep the html as clean as possible and move all functionality to the js angular script, don't know if this is correct though

Comment: It is upto you. With my way you are doing job in just in a line. And HTML is as clean as it is with function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 points wrong here, you're calling your function wrongly:

```
{{exercise.increase($index)}}
```

should be

```
increase($index)
```

and you're treating `$index` as an object, it should be like so:

```
$scope.increase = function($index) {
    $scope.exercises[$index].count++;
};
```

Comment: Also the increase is on the scope, so call it like this: `ng-click="increase($index)"`

Comment: @OlivérKovács Updated my answer, noticed it while you were commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<span class="increase" ng-click="{{exercise.increase($index)}}">+</span>
```

to:

```
<span class="increase" ng-click="exercise.increase($index)">+</span>
```

The braces aren't needed in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your result without calling a function and doing stuff just inside `ng-click` itself.

```
<span class="increase" ng-click="exercises.count =exercises.count+1 ">+</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<span class="increase" ng-click="increase($index)">+</span>
```

and you controller

```
$index = $index + 1;
```